# debug typescript (.ts) files in brower from JS files generated through webpack

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, asp.net-core

I have just started learning ASP.NET Core and basics of TypeScript. I have the following object class:

```
export class StoreCustomer {
    constructor(private firstName: string, private lastName: string) {
    }

    public ShowName() {
        alert(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }
}
```

And the following main.ts class:

```
import { StoreCustomer } from "./storecustomer";

let a = new StoreCustomer("FirstName", "LastName");
a.ShowName();
```

Both TS files are present in `wwwroot` folder. When I reference the trans piled JS files in my HTML page, I get the error saying `exports` is not defined. I learned that you need to use a module loader to solve this issue, so I installed `webpack` in my project through `NPM`. `webpack` again generates new JS files which when referenced in my HTML page, I get the desired output. But the problem is, since the TS files are not in the same directory and I cannot generate the js files in the same folder as the TS files, I am not able to debug the TS files in the browser. How can I debug TS files from JS files generated through `webpack`?

EDIT:

My webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
        entry: {
            main: './wwwroot/ts/main.js',
            storecustomer: './wwwroot/ts/storecustomer.js',
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './wwwroot/scripts'),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },
        devtool: "source-map",
    };
```

Comment: If you're using webpack then enable sourcemap (dev-tool options). Do you see webpack folder in "Source" tab in chrome browser.

Comment: @MithunPattankar added my `webpack.config.js` in the question. I have added `devtool: "source-map"` and I am able to see `webpack` in browser which lists the transpiled JS files and I am also able to debug them. But I want to debug the TypeScript files instead of JavaScript files.

Comment: do look into the all the sub folder in webpack, you will see the TS files, try this setting " devtool: 'eval-source-map' "

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack configuration, you are starting from the .js files, that is the reason that the .map files point to the .js files.

If you want to see the TypeScript files, you need to configure your webpack to use `ts-loader` (https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/):

For example:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    use: 'ts-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
]
```